# How to resolve HostedService in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to add a Background Timer in ASP.NET Core 3.0, which periodically executes a task.
Google led me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), where I implemented the 'Timed background tasks'.
However, I'm stuck in resolving the HostedService in the controller.
I need a specific instance of TimedHealthCheckService so I can call another public function called 'GetAvailableODataUrl()'.

---

In the `startup.cs` I use the following code:

```
services.AddHostedService<TimedHealthCheckService>();
```

The TimedHealthCheckService obviously implements IHostedService:

```
public class TimedHealthCheckService : IHostedService, IDisposable
```

In my controller, I have the following constructor:

```
public HealthCheckController(ILogger<HealthCheckController> logger, IHostedService hostedService)
{
  this.logger = logger;
  this.timedHealthCheckService = hostedService as TimedHealthCheckService;
}
```

However, when I start my WebAPI, the `timedHealthCheckService` is always null.
It seems another IHostedService gets injected into the constructor. By checking hostedService, it is actually an object of type GenericWebHostService.

If I change the controller's constructor to:

```
public HealthCheckController(ILogger<HealthCheckController> logger, TimedHealthCheckService hostedService)
```

I am getting the following error:

*Unable to resolve service for type 'HealthCheck.Web.TimedHealthCheckService' while attempting to activate 'HealthCheck.Web.Controllers.HealthCheckController'.*

I also tried `services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, TimedHealthCheckService>();` with the same result.

Comment: Why do you need to inject the hosted service? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: hosted services are automatically started by the framework so I am trying to understand why you need to get an instance of the service injected into the controller.

Comment: @Nkosi This hostedService will hold the actual health state. So I would like to get this state directly from the hostedService.

Comment: I suggest changing the design. Have an intermediate service that can be injected into both the controller and the hosted service. Make the service singleton so that state can be shared between them

Comment: @Nkosi I guess that's a viable option, thank you. However, I am still wondering why IHostedService cannot be injected as expected. Is it by design?

Comment: A whole bunch of things implement IHostedService.  When you request an IHostedService, the framework doesn't know which one to give you.  So it picks one (I don't know how) and gives it to you.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try these two lines in startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<TimedHealthCheckService>();
services.AddHostedService<TimedHealthCheckService>(provider => provider.GetService<TimedHealthCheckService>());
```

The first line above tells the service provider to create a singleton and give it to anyone who wants a `TimedHealthCheckService`, like your controller's constructor.  However, the service provider is unaware that the singleton is actually an `IHostedService` and that you want it to call `StartAsync()`.

The second line tells the service provider that you want to add a hosted service, so it'll call `StartAsync()` when the application starts running.  `AddHostedService` accepts a `Func<IServiceProvider,THostedService>` callback.  The callback we provide fetches the singleton `TimedHealthCheckService` from the service provider and returns it back to the service provider as an `IHostedService`.  The service provider then calls its `StartAsync()` function.

And in your controller:

```
public HealthCheckController(ILogger<HealthCheckController> logger, TimedHealthCheckService hostedService)
```

Comment: Perfect, now it works, thank you. Can you elaborate on why a IServiceProvider is needed?

Comment: in asp.net core 2.1 AddHostedService doesn't accept arguments. any suggestions how to bypass this?

Comment: The documentation claims that the overload of AddHostedService that takes a Func<> parameter is available in 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions_AddHostedService__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__

Comment: Hello @jeffrey Rennie, how to mock TimedHealthCheckService in XUNIT please?

Comment: Great! I also wonder why my class constructor is called twice even though I add it as "Singleton". So, the "Singleton" instance is used HostedSerivce unless I follow this answer.